# Story identification: post-apocalyptic short story about mutant children returning to their parents

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

This is a short story, probably horror. It may have been part of an anthology.

The setting is non-specific, but some event has occurred that causes some children to be born deformed.

Rather than murder their children, the parents take the child down to a lake that is perpetually misty and send it out in a small boat or basket. They do this for many years, until one day a boat is seen coming across the lake.

The children have returned.

First encounters are peaceful, until something causes someone to fire a rifle or somesuch. Much fighting ensues.

The narrator (I believe) and her husband return to their home where they find their own son who they sent off years ago. He is dying of a bullet wound, and dies in his mother’s arms. The son may kill the father.

Specific things I remember:

- The child of the narrator has large eyes. I think they are either described as milky white and plate-sized, or pendulous and hanging from his head. He is also very tall.
- The boat the children return in is covered with scales or plates of some kind.
- One of the grown children has either a pincer arm or a pincer mouth.
- The general aesthetic is Puritan, but could be wrong on that.
- It was horrifically violent in parts.

I read it in school, around 2012. However, it was a photocopy from a book so I cannot give any further details towards its age.

I was in Australia, and the story was in English, but I don’t believe that it was necessarily written in Australia. It was read for a philosophy class, if that helps.

Comment: Sounds interesting. I hope someone can help because my interest has also been piqued. When did you read the story, what language was it in, and what country were you in?

Comment: I read it in school, around 2012. However, it was a photocopy from an book, so I cannot give any further details towards its age. It was in English. It was was read within Australia, but I don’t believe that it was an Australian text. It was read for a philosophy class, so perhaps it had some vague philosophical implications? We also read Harrison Bergeron, if that aids in finding any anthologies it may have been in.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! We recommend the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour) to all new users. Your question is a solid start, but you may want to look at the answers to [this question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/) for tips on additional info to help identify your story.

Comment: @Gary Were the two stories from the same anthology? Here is the ISFDB page for anthologies and publications containing Harrison Bergeron... Are any of those entries jogging your memory?  http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?41335

Comment: (Clicking the "View all covers" link at the bottom will show anthology covers containing Harrison Bergeron. Hope that helps.)

Comment: There was no cover on the text I was reading as it was a photocopy. I only say that it might have been part of an anthology as that is a common way to resource texts in the classroom, and the two were read close to one another. But thank you for the help, I will read through them!

Comment: I read this in the 1980's in school and believe it had been around a while since then. I, too, am searching for it again.